# Setting CMake curl variables for building curlpp

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, curlpp

I use C++, curl 7.64, CMake 3.19.3, curlpp 0.8.1, Windows 7 OS. I cannot build curlpp out-of-the-box.
`CURL_FOUND` is set to true, but `CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `CURL_LIBRARIES` are empty (AFAIK, CMake module delegates variables filling to curl CMake module).

I've set CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS manually, but setting CURL_LIBRARIES="debug "path_to_debug" optimized "path_to_release"" fails. So, I've got linker errors.

BTW, why do some curl-consuming CMakeLists.txt files use `${CURL_LIBRARIES}`
and the other ones use `CURL::libcurl` for feeding `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: Have you read CMake documentation about [FindCURL](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCURL.html) module? In the last paragraph they explain, that if CURL is built with CMake, then it provides Config file, and `find_package(CURL)` just processes this file. The Config file provides only `CURL::curl` imported target, without variable like `CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `CURL_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: OK, but curlpp relies on these variables. Is it possible to build dynamic and static curlpp without patching curlpp CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: So, is curlpp author's approach with `CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `CURL_LIBRARIES` obsolete?